# How to include more than one value in IN operator in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query that is working fine in Big Query:

```sql
SELECT
date,
nombre,
i.identifier,
i.hour
FROM
  `table` t, unnest(identifier_s) i
where 2 in unnest(i.hour)
```

However, I need to include more integers in the search value of the IN operator. Something like this:

`...where (2 or 5 or 6) in unnest...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example - hope yo will be able to adopt it to your specific use-case

```
select date, nombre, i.identifier, i.hour 
from `adsmovil-produccion.analisis_alejandro.100_temp_pers` t, 
unnest(identifier_s) i 
where exists (
  select 1
  from unnest(i.hour) x
  join unnest([2, 5, 6]) x
  using(x)
)
```